# MySQL Syntax error: unexpected keyword_do_block

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby and trying to complete a tutorial that I can't get to work properly.  I am attempting to run `rake db:migrate` on my root folder and is giving me 3 separate error messages:

```
>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: 
C:/Users/Bill/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20170922050429_create_use
rs.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
create_table :users, do |t|
                       ^
C:/Users/Bill/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20170922050429_create_users.rb:5: 
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
    t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
              ^
C:/Users/Bill/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20170922050429_create_users.rb:5: 
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
                          ^

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The Ruby code from my `create_users.rb` file is:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users, do |t|
        t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
        t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
        t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
        t.string "password", :limit => 40
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
def change
  create_table :users, do |t|
    t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
    t.string "password", :limit => 40
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

You have:

```
create_table :users, do |t|
```

which should be:

```
create_table :users do |t|
```

There should not be any comma after that unless you have more than one arguments there.

**Update:**

And also you `class` has no `end` which will not close the class definition and throw exception.

**On a side note:**

You have this line:

```
t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
```

which can be written as:

```
t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That cleared up most of the issues, thanks!  Now just getting an error for: "unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end end^" on line 11?

Comment: Just add one more `end` the last. As your class has no `end` statement

Answer (score 2):

in addition to first answer. Why don't you use rails generators?

Write migrations can be usefull when you have to modify something. Faster and cleaner way is using rails generators:

Example:

```
rails g model User first_name:string last_name:string
```

If attributes are string you can just

```
rails g model User first_name last_name
```

It will generate class User in /app/models/user.rb and migration for database.

Also you have Scaffold, and others generators.

More info: [Command Line Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

**Tip**: Check for Devise Gem, it will generate entire structure for User Model.

Link: [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)